# String manipulation on column in Google Sheet Query

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

Is it possible to do a string manipulation of data in a Google Sheet query?

I want to do something like the following:

```
=QUERY(someRange!A:Z, SELECT A, SUBSTITUTE(B, "OCH", ""))
```

The idea being that all rows' column B is 'OCHXXXXXXX' where X is a digit. I would like to get rid of the chars.

On a side note... Is this possible in MySQL? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This formula might work for you:

`=QUERY({Sheet1!A:A,ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(Sheet1!B:B,"OCH","")),Sheet1!C:Z})`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

```
=arrayformula(REGEXREPLACE(somerange!B:B, "OCH", ""))
```